# is it possible to make kubernetes ingress treafik apply to all namespace

Tags: kubernetes

Now I am using treafik to expose my pods service to external,but I read the treafik deploy document and find out treafik forward request only in one namespace.For example, A namespaces request could not forward to B namespace ,should I deploy multi-treafik in kubernetes cluster?Now I have 6 namespace,should I deploy 6 treafik? It is wired, what is the best practice about this situation? I found from internet but find nothing talking about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this is unfortunately not possible and it was a conscious decision to do it that way:

> Cross namespace references would be a prime source of privilege
>   escalation attacks.

But in case you don't care about security rules there is a workaround (bear in mind that it will not work on every platform). You need to use Kubernetes services of type `externalName`, which would reference the services from your other namespaces. See the example below:

a. you have `serviceA` in `namespaceA`

b. create `serviceB` in `namespaceB`

```
spec:
    ...
    type: ExertalName
    externalName: serviceA.namespaceA.svc.cluster.local
```

c. add ingress rule into `ingressB` in `namespaceB`

```
 - path: /****
    backend:
      serviceName: serviceB
      servicePort: ***
```

However it would be safer if you just deploy multiple ingress treafiks for each namespace.

I hope it helps.